# Kuberentes kubelet-client-current.pem expired

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubeadm

I'm new in K8s and I'm facing a problem with certificate.
1.13 version is used.
One of the worker nodes is in NotReady status.
I check logs and it turned out that:

**Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired

Using bootstrap kubeconfig to generate TLS client cert, key and kubeconfig file

Loading cert/key pair from "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem"

Failed to connect to apiserver: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials**

I checked and indeed kubelet-client-current.pem is pointing to expired certificate. My question is how to renew this kubelet-client-<current_date>.pem file.

EDIT:
I read that for this current cert:
*The initial validity period is one year. When the certificate is about to expire, it is automatically renewed and the validity period is extended by one year.*
Is there any way to create it manually? Or how to force kubeadm to do it?

I also deleted /var/lib/kubelet/pki and after kubelet restart it was recreated but only with kubelet-client.key.tmp,  kubelet.crt,  kubelet.key.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to renew this certificate.
Solution is described under https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#kubelet-client-cert